# Only able to drag draggable element once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm working on a small app where I drag element to a droppable area. I recently upgraded to jQuery 1.5 and I discovered that I can only drag an element once.

That means that if the user accidently drops it somewhere else other than the droppable element, he will not be able to drag it again.

I am using jQuery 1.5 and jQuery UI 1.8.9.

I set the draggable state to each element via a .each function.

Has anybody else had this problem? I'm a jQuery novice, and I am thankful for any help :)

```
    $(itemId).draggable({ 
    zIndex: 2700,
    helper: "clone",
    scroll: false,
    drag: function(event, ui) 
    {
        $("#container").css("background-color", "#fff");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) 
    {
        $("#conatiner").css("background-color", "#F0EBE0");

    }
});
```

[EDIT] I should also add that I have delegated a click event to the same object with the delegate function. Although it wasn't a problem before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug introduced with jQuery 1.5, and it will be fixed in jQuery 1.5.1:
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6922

You'll need to revert back to jQuery 1.4.4 until 1.5.1 is released.

Comment: Thank you! I'll think I will wait for the next version of jQuery.

Comment: Yep I had this same issue and this worked for me.  Im now using 1.6.1 and the problem has gone